# Определить сложность алгоритма программы

Tags: c#

не могу правильно выявить сложность алгоритма программы. Программа  составляет наибольшее возможное число из десятичных разрядов,  цифры задаются пользователем.

```
using System;

namespace lb3
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int index;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите строку");
            string data = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] mas = data.ToCharArray();
            char[] result = new char[mas.Length];
            int i = 0;
            while (i < mas.Length)
            {
                result[i] = Search(mas);
                mas[index] = ' ';
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
            while (i < result.Length)
            {
                Console.Write(result[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
        static char Search(char[] d)
        {
            int i = 1;
            char max = d[0];
            index = 0;
            while (i < d.Length)
            {
                if (d[i] != ' ')
                {
                    if (d[i] > max)
                    {
                        max = d[i];
                        index = i;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: сложность O(n^2)

Comment: O(n^2) - количество операций растет квадратично. Сначала проход по массиву, потом search() еще раз проход по массиву - соответственно квадратично

Comment: @Barmaley while (i < mas.Length) result[i] = Search() c while получается n^2

Comment: Да, поторопился - уже исправил

Comment: Всем спасибо за оперативность , теперь понял)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ сложность О(n^2)

1. while (i < mas.Length) дает О(n)

   ```
        while (i < mas.Length)
        {
            result[i] = Search(mas);// без учета
            mas[index] = ' '; 
            i++;
        }
   ```
2. Search() c while дает О(n)

   ```
        while (i < d.Length)
        {
            if (d[i] != ' ')
            {
                if (d[i] > max)
                {
                    max = d[i];
                    index = i;
                }
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
   ```
3. итого получается О(n^2)

   ```
        while (i < mas.Length)
        {
            result[i] = Search(mas);
            mas[index] = ' ';
            i++;
        }
   ```

PS цикл

```
       while (i < result.Length)
        {
            Console.Write(result[i]);
            i++;
        }
```

можно пренебреч поскольку O(n) намного лучше и он не будет влиять сильно на окончательную оценку

Comment: Угу, причём очевидно, что алгоритм программы можно улучшить тривиальным способом - отсортировать по убыванию цифры и просто выдать ответ из них. Сложность алгоритма упрётся в сложность алгоритма сортировки, которую обычно принимают за nlogn (в среднем).

Comment: @AK согласен. Но задача оценить а не улучшить